# How do I edit the string of a function in includes/abstracts directly?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For example the function `get_price_html_from_to()` in file `plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php`

```
public function get_price_html_from_to( $from, $to ) {
    return '<del>' . ( ( is_numeric( $from ) ) ? wc_price( $from ) : $from ) . '</del> <ins>' . ( ( is_numeric( $to ) ) ? wc_price( $to ) : $to ) . '</ins>';
}
```

Without going into the file itself and changing it, how do I alter that string?

Is it possible to create my own `abstract-wc-product.php`file, and point wordpress/woo at the file instead of the original? or is there a way to simply remove & replace the function with one of my own? or just alter it's string before it gets used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don`t change the templates as you will loose your changed once there is an update. Instead, add your method to the filter:

```
    dd_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'your_function_name', 100, 2 );
    function your_function_name( $price, $product ){
         return 'Was:' . str_replace( '<ins>', ' Now:<ins>', $price );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

One way i think you can make this work, is by declaring your **new** function  `get_price_html_from_to( $from, $to )` before you include `abstract-wc-product.php` file. 
And then going in the `abstract-wc-product.php` file and adding this code near the function's `get_price_html_from_to( $from, $to )` definition :

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_price_html_from_to' ) )
    public function get_price_html_from_to( $from, $to ) {
    return '<del>' . ( ( is_numeric( $from ) ) ? wc_price( $from ) : $from ) . '</del> <ins>' . ( (       is_numeric( $to ) ) ? wc_price( $to ) : $to ) . '</ins>';
}
```

}

Though that requires you to go in the file and actually change it.. really *slightly* though.

Comment: any changes to the original woocommerce file in `plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php` will be erased in any update. Thus, everything has to exist outside plugins/woocommerce

Comment: this is true however thats the only way i can think of, to do what you need, i have ran through that problem myself in my wordpress site recently and i used the solution i described, i am not sure if user2683419 solution works , the `add_filter` function i believe he meant not `dd_filter`... and also i dont think wordpress updates that often , and adding 2 rows on a file it hard enough to keep you from doing it on every update (especially if you only need to change a couple of functions), maybe thats just my opinion

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-override-a-function
check this relevant link , could be helpful , read the 3 last posts on that topic

Comment: came across that before, doesn't work, I think it may be outdated.

This is an example, I'm going to be doing this dozens if not a hundred times through out files, thats too many to trouble shoot after every update. I want to build this site and leave it for others, I do not want it to require constant updating by a single person who knows the locations of a 100 changes.

I'd like either a logical file directory, or a single file clearly labeled.

Comment: i see your point, i haven't found any ways to achieve that yet